# Chrome freezes when closing a $uibModal instance

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Hej

When testing one of the modal windows on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal my chrome browser freezes for about 50 seconds after I close the modal. For this time I can not do anything in that specific browser tab. I can not even scroll.

The console output does not show any errors.

I implemented the component modal in my own web app and the same happens.

Does anybody know about that issue?

Version of angular: 1.5.0

Version of angular-ui-bootstrap: 2.4.0

Version og Google Chrome: 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Btw: In Safari everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across with a similar issue. and Then figure out it's because of the CSS Display:block Attribute check try making it in to null on your modal div. this will take you in to the modal and out from it smoothly.

Hope this will help you some how.